# How to scope materialize css?

Tags: css, materialize

I am having an plug and play tool which can be plugged with any website, i had used [materialize](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize) as my css framework, the problem is when i am hooking my plug and play tool to another portal which uses bootstrap or any other css framework, both portal and my tool css is getting tampered because of conflict

how can i resolve the above issue ??

one way i can find is to scope it, but it would be a framework level change , but does materialize provide any stuff by which i can scope it